# Import Flat File to MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to import a CSV into MSSQL 2008 by using the flat file import method but I am getting an Overflow error. Any ideas on how to go around it?

I used the tool before for files containing up to 10K-15K records but this file has 75K records in it....

These are the error messages

```
Messages
Error 0xc020209c: Data Flow Task 1: The column data for column "ClientBrandID" overflowed the disk I/O buffer.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0202091: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while skipping data rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Shows_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: Show us the command you are trying to use.

Comment: I am not using actual commands. I am using the wizard tool

Comment: 75K shouldn't be that many rows... but in the wizard, did you specify the column types (so that there are no possible type mismatches)? Else, try to link the csv file instead and query from the linked table.

Comment: The columns match and I don't know how the link works. can post a link to an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a format problem of the csv file e.g. the delimiter. Check if the delimiters are consistent within the file.
It could also be a problem of blank lines. I had a similar problem a while ago. I've solved it by removing all blank lines in the csv file. Worth a try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may have one or more bad data elements. Try loading a small subset of your data to determine if it's a small number of bad records or a large one. This will also tell you if your loading scheme is working and your datatypes match.

Sometimes you can quickly spot data issues if you open the csv file in excel.

Comment: OK, split the file in half, see if one half loads and the other doesn't. Then split the bad file in half again, etc. What you're hoping is you only have a few bad records.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason for this error is that input file has wrong encoding. So, when you manually check data, it seems fine. For example, in my case correct files were in 8-bit ANSI, and wrong files in UTF-16 - you can tell the difference by looking at files size, wrong files were twice bigger than correct files.